# Is there more documentation for tpx describing keyboard commands?

Tags: diagrams, editors, keyboard

I am new to TpX, the GUI image editor for Latex. I am experimenting with Bezier curves. I found that one can "drop" the curve by pressing double-click. I have not been able to find this fact in the documentation I have. In the readme file, double-click is said to be for editing object properties but I would not have guessed that it is also for finishing drawing the curve. Is there documentation describing this, e.g. a tutorial? (I would have tagged this with Tpx but I am not allowed to).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The project seems to have been stuck for more than ten years.